# input dialog box matlab check if empty

Tags: matlab

Why does `isempty` return `0` instead of returning `1` when nothing is entered by the user?

```
>> prompt1 = {' Video Name:'};
dlg_title = 'Input';
num_lines = 1;
answer1 = inputdlg(prompt1,dlg_title,num_lines);
>> isempty(answer1)
```

`ans = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inputdlg` function returns empty answer only if the user pressed the cancel button. That is, `isempty(answer1)` can be used to check if the user pressed 'Ok' or 'Cancel'.
If you want to check if the user pressed 'Ok' without typing anything, try `strcmp(answer1,'')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
isempty(answer{1})
```

since it is a cell array